# Two access points with same SSID, loosing connectivity on mobile devices

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, dhcp, ssid

I have two access points, with the same SSID, same security mode (WPA/WPA2), operating at different channels (1 and 6). I have set the first of them (192.168.1.1) to operate as a DHCP server, while the second one has DHCP disabled, only having a static IP address (192.168.1.2).

My laptop connects fine to the second access point (when I'm in its range), receives an IP address, and always has connectivity to the Internet. My mobile devices (HTC Sensation & Nexus 7) connect as well, receive their IP addresses, but sometimes (usually when not active) they lose **Internet** connectivity, while maintaining full signal. When I check with Fing, I see that they cannot reach the main access point (192.168.1.1), and devices connected to the first access point. I have to restart the second access point for it to work again.

What makes me wonder is the fact that this never happens with my laptop. Am I missing something in my configuration?

Comment: When the second router is in its failed stated, does the laptop continue to work?

Comment: Yes, and surprisingly still connected to the same router

Comment: Can't you just set up the 2nd AP as a repeater?

Comment: @ott Not the same, at all.

Comment: I also have 2 APs in a building, but both are beyond the same router and dhcp-server. Is it possible that you switch to such a configuration?

Comment: @ott no that's not an option right now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by disabling "VLAN Function" on my second access point. I'm not exactly sure as to why this might have caused a problem, but one thing I know for sure, and that is the fact that I'm not encountering the problem mentioned in the question anymore.

Maybe someone who knows why this might have fixed the problem would like to share his/her idea, so that other readers will benefit.